# Вопрос по конструктору форм в Yii

Tags: yii

Изучаю Yii на примере создания простого блога с офсайта фреймворка. На этой странице есть описание:

Отдельно следует описать использование "списочных" типов dropdownlist, checkboxlist и radiolist. Для них необходимо задать свойство items соответствующего элемента input. Сделать это можно так:

```
'gender'=>array(
    'type'=>'dropdownlist',
    'items'=>User::model()->getGenderOptions(),
    'prompt'=>'Выберите значение:',
),

…

class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function getGenderOptions()
    {
        return array(
            0 => 'Мужчина',
            1 => 'Женщина',
        );
    }
}
```

Данный код сгенерирует выпадающий список с текстом «Выберите значение:» и опциями «Мужчина» и «Женщина», которые мы получаем из метода getGenderOptions модели User.

Кроме данных типов полей, в свойстве type можно указать класс или псевдоним пути виджета. Класс виджета должен наследовать CInputWidget или CJuiInputWidget. В ходе генерации элемента формы будет создан и выполнен экземпляр класса виджета. Виджет будет использовать конфигурацию, переданную через настройки элемента формы.

Добавил это в файл настроек loginForm.php в папке view, добавил в User.php метод getGenderOptions() и все равно у меня ничего не появляется. Редактировать элементы login и password в loginForm.php получается, а добавляя новые ничего не меняется. Помогите пожалуйста. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что конкретно у вас не получается, не выводиться выпадающий список? Что значит "добавляя новые ничего не меняется", что такое новые?

Comment: Да. Не выводится выпадающий список

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CForm выводит только безопасные поля, то есть вам требуеться добавить ваше поле в правила валидации, к примеру вот так:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...
        array('gender', 'safe'),
        ...
    );
}
```

Не нашел данного поведения в описании работы с конструктором форм, только метод который проверяет данное [CFormInputElement::evaluateVisible()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormInputElement#evaluateVisible-detail), он участвует в методе проверки видимости выводимого элемента.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял!